# event.target doesn't work properly after trigger('click') on chrome

Tags: jquery, triggers

This an example and not my real code.

```
function upload(){
   event.preventDefault();
   var elemento=$(event.target);
   console.log(elemento);
}

function prepareUpload(){
   event.preventDefault();
   $("#upload").trigger("click");
}

<button id="prepareUpload" onclick="prepareUpload()" type="submit"/>
<button id="upload" onclick="upload()"/>
```

In Chrome if I click the upload button I can see in the console that the element has the id "upload" which is correct but if I click the prepareUpload button I see the id "prepareUpload". I can't try in the same way on Firefox but it seems it works properly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do as below:

```
<button id="prepareUpload" type="submit">Any Text</button>
<button id="upload">Upload</button>

$(document).on("click","#upload",function(event){
   event.preventDefault();
   var elemento=$(event.target);
   console.log(elemento);
});

$(document).on("click","#prepareUpload",function(event){
   event.preventDefault();
   $("#upload").trigger("click");
});
```

Comment: Oops!! Sorry for that.. :) Will do now.. :) Thanks for that.. :)

Comment: Tnanks, is because of the variable event whithout it event.target is wrong. That's why it worked in Firefox (I had to pass event mandatorily) and not in Chrome (variable event is optional)

Comment: Anytime!! :) Happy Coding.. :)